# Calculate if bitmap will fit in memory before creating it

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have some text data that i would like to convert to a bitmap.
in order to do that i need to create a bitmap then bind the canvas to it on draw the text using the canvas..

what i want to do is, before creating the bitmap, calculate the size of the bitmap that i need and check if it can fit in the memory. if not i will split the text.

**Is there any way to check if a bitmap fits in the memory before creating it ?**

I need a possible implementation of a function like this:

```
private boolean bitmapWillFitInMemory(int width,int height, Bitmap.Config config)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: simple math: `width * height * bytesperpixel (4 for RGB8888)` ... to get w and h use BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds ... better solution is to read: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: I don't decode any files or resources. Its a bitmap that i create but if i will not find any cleaner solution i will compare the bitmap size to the available memory size. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this might help you to determine how much memory left for your application after calculating your bitmap size:

```
Double allocated = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize())/new Double((1048576));
Double available = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapSize())/1048576.0;
Double free = new Double(Debug.getNativeHeapFreeSize())/1048576.0;
```

Comment: Thanks very much. i might use it to compare with the bitmap size if i will not find a better solution. also, im not absolutely sure but i think i read somewhere that since version 3 the bitmaps are allocated on the Delvik heap instead of the native heap. anyway thanks very much!